# N:M association error when using include.through

Tags: sequelize.js

### Scenario

A User can have many Tag objects. A Tag object belongs to one user. A Tag has many Transactions. A Transaction belongs to one Tag. Users have many Transactions. A Transaction can have many User.

### Models

```
var User = sequelize.define('User', {
      id: {
          type: Sequelize.BIGINT,
          autoIncrement: true,
          primaryKey: true
      },

      ...

  }, { timestamps: false, freezeTableName: true, tableName: 'register'});


var Tag = sequelize.define('Tag', {
      tagId: {
          type: Sequelize.STRING(50),
          primaryKey: true,
          allowNull: false
      },

      ...

  }, { timestamps: false, freezeTableName: true, tableName: 'tag'});


var Transaction = sequelize.define('Transaction', {
      id: {
          type: Sequelize.BIGINT,
          autoIncrement: true,
          primaryKey: true
      },
      active: {
          type: Sequelize.BOOLEAN,
          defaultValue: true
      }
  }, { timestamps: false, freezeTableName: true, tableName: 'transaction'});


var UserTx = sequelize.define('UserTx', {
    id: {
        type: Sequelize.BIGINT,
        autoIncrement: true,
        primaryKey: true
    }
  },
  { timestamps: false, freezeTableName: true, tableName: 'user_transaction'});
```

### Relations

```
User.hasMany(Tag, {foreignKey: 'owner_id', foreignKeyConstraint: true});
Tag.belongsTo(User, {foreignKey: 'owner_id', foreignKeyConstraint: true});

Tag.hasMany(Transaction, {foreignKey: 'tag_id', foreignKeyConstraint: true});
Transaction.belongsTo(Tag, {foreignKey: 'tag_id', foreignKeyConstraint: true});

User.belongsToMany(Transaction, {through: {model: UserTx, unique: false}, foreignKey: 'user_id'});
Transaction.belongsToMany(User, {through: {model: UserTx, unique: false}, foreignKey: 'tx_id'});
```

### Problem

I am trying to return a list of Tag objects owned by a given user, in addition to Tag objects that the user has associated Transactions for. In plain SQL:

```
select * from tag 
left outer join transaction on tag."tagId" = transaction.tag_id 
left outer join user_transaction on transaction.id = user_transaction.tx_id 
where tag.owner_id = ? or user_transaction.user_id = ?
```

My current Sequelize query:

```
Tag.findAll({
      where: { owner_id: userId }, // missing OR user_transaction.user_id = userId
      include: [{
        model: Transaction,
        attributes: ['id'],
        through: {model: UserTx, where: {user_id: userId}, attributes: ['user_id', 'tx_id']},
        where: {
          active: true
        },
        required: false, // include Tags that do not have an associated Transaction
      }]
})
```

When this query is called, I get the following error:

```
Unhandled rejection TypeError: Cannot call method 'replace' of undefined
at Object.module.exports.removeTicks (/site/services/node_modules/sequelize/lib/utils.js:343:14)
at Object.module.exports.addTicks (/site/services/node_modules/sequelize/lib/utils.js:339:29)
at Object.QueryGenerator.quoteIdentifier (/site/services/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/postgres/query-generator.js:843:20)
at generateJoinQueries (/site/services/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/abstract/query-generator.js:1207:72)
at Object.<anonymous> (/site/services/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/abstract/query-generator.js:1388:27)
at Array.forEach (native)
at Object.QueryGenerator.selectQuery (/site/services/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/abstract/query-generator.js:1387:10)
at QueryInterface.select (/site/services/node_modules/sequelize/lib/query-interface.js:679:25)
at null.<anonymous> (/site/services/node_modules/sequelize/lib/model.js:1386:32)
```

Setting a breakpoint in the removeTicks function and setting a watch on 's' (the column name attribute), I notice the following:

```
s = "Transactions"
s = "Transactions.id"
s = "Transactions.undefined" // should be Transactions.UserTx ?
s = "user_id"
s = "Transactions.undefined.user_id"
s = "Transactions.undefined"
s = "tx_id"
s = "Transactions.undefined.tx_id"
```

Is my usage of N:M incorrect? I have used the 'through' construct in a 'find' query elsewhere  with success, but as this 'through' is nested in an include, it seems to be behaving differently (such as requiring me to pass through.model explicitly)

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Reproducing `TypeError: Cannot call method 'replace' of undefined`**

The n:m relations you define look fine to me. I have reproduced the TypeError in a [test script](https://github.com/cfogelberg/sequelize-playground/tree/master/tests/05-nm-through-error) and your usage of `through.where` looks fine to me as well (documentation [here](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/api/model/?highlight=aggregate#findalloptions-promisearrayinstance)). This could be a bug in Sequelize.

**Ways that work for your problem**

One way of finding all tags owned by user X, or which have 1+ transactions associated with user X, is to use 2 calls to findAll and then dedupe the results:

```
function using_two_findall(user_id) {
  var tags_associated_via_tx = models.tag.findAll({
    include: [{
      model: models.transaction,
      include: [{
        model: models.user,
        where: { id: user_id }
      }]
    }]
  });

  var tags_owned_by_user = models.tag.findAll({
    where: { owner_id: user_id }
  });

  return Promise.all([tags_associated_via_tx, tags_owned_by_user])
  .spread(function(tags_associated_via_tx, tags_owned_by_user) {
    // dedupe the two arrays of tags:
    return _.uniq(_.flatten(tags_associated_via_tx, tags_owned_by_user), 'id')
  });
}
```

Another method is to use a raw query like you suggest:

```
function using_raw_query(user_id) {
  var sql = 'select s05.tag.id, s05.tag.owner_id from s05.tag ' +
            'where s05.tag.owner_id = ' + user_id + ' ' +
            'union ' +
            'select s05.tag.id, s05.tag.owner_id from s05.tag, s05.transaction, s05.user_tx ' +
            'where s05.tag.id = s05.transaction.tag_id and s05.user_tx.tx_id = s05.transaction.id and ' +
            's05.user_tx.user_id = ' + user_id;

  return sq.query(sql, { type: sq.QueryTypes.SELECT})
  .then(function(data_array) {
    return _.map(data_array, function(data) {
      return models.tag.build(data, { isNewRecord: false });;
    });
  })
  .catch(function(err) {
    console.error(err);
    console.error(err.stack);
    return err;
  });
}
```

You can see both techniques in the test script that is linked above in this answer.

As a quick note you can see my raw query is a bit different to yours. When I ran yours it didn't generate output that matched the problem description. Also, as another quick note, my raw SQL query uses a union. Sequelize currently [doesn't support them](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/4293) via the find API.

**Performance?**

Just looking at the SQL generated, the raw query is going to be faster than the two calls to findAll. On the other hand, the two calls to findAll are clearer and premature optimisation is stupid. Whichever technique I used I'd wrap it in a [class method](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/docs/models-definition/#expansion-of-models) anyway :)

Comment: Submitted an issue to sequelize github here: https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/4866

Comment: Thanks for your effort to diagnose the problem, as well as following up by posting an issue on Github. I ended up doing two separate findAll queries. Excellent tip with using lodash's dedupe function.